# JSON - cannot read property length of undefined

Tags: jquery, json, kendo-datasource, kendo-panelbar

I'm trying to make a kendo panelbar with a kendo datasource. I'm getting a 'cannot read property length of undefined' in the jquery.min.js file on this line `var panelBar = $("#foodGroups").kendoPanelBar({dataSource: ds }).data("kendoPanelBar");`. I think it is because of my datasource. Here is an example of a kendo datasource format [example](http://jsfiddle.net/MMRCf/8/light/). Is my datasource data not in the correct format? Code:

```
function populateFoodGroups() {

var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({});

      var pData = [];    
if (_theFoodGroups.length > 0) {
        var groups = [];
        for(var y = 0; y < _selectedMealType.allMealFoodGroup.Code.length; y ++) {
            pData.push({text:_selectedMealType.allMealFoodGroup.Code[y].description,
                        contentUrl: 'file:///data/data/VCare.International.Observations/files/12590FAA-5EDD-4B12-856D-F52A0A1599F2/Views/Phone/checkboxes.html'});



            if($.inArray(_selectedMealType.allMealFoodGroup.Code[y].myMealFoodGroup.description, groups) === -1){

                groups.push({text: _selectedMealType.allMealFoodGroup.Code[y].myMealFoodGroup.description, content: pData[y]});
            }
        }



        for(var z = 0; z < groups.length; z ++) {
            //panelBar.append({text: groups[z].text, items: pData[z]});
            ds.add({text: groups[z].text, items: groups[z].content});
        }

   var panelBar = $("#foodGroups").kendoPanelBar({dataSource: ds }).data("kendoPanelBar");

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Currently PanelBar and Menu do not support data binding to a Kendo DataSource and their dataSource option is used to load a JSON initialization object instead." - [posted on telerik forums in this answer](http://www.telerik.com/forums/panelbar-datasource-usage#oj4f_nU15kKTHUImhF1P7A)

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the solution provided for the question given below

[Loading of Kendo UI panelbar using datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718665/loading-of-kendoui-panelbar-using-datasource)